# Convert API String to JSON Object using NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I've read numerous threads asking similar questions but have been unable to tie it all together.

I have an API feeding a string here: https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/constants/exchangerates/local

I would like to make this string usable and accessible. For example getting the USD to CAD rate.

I'm using RestSharp and Newtonsoft JSON in my code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
```

First I used http://json2csharp.com/ to create a class (classes?) matching the string. EDIT: I've now solved this, and had to nest the classes properly, as per revised code;

```
class Exrates
{
    public Rates rates { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }

    public class Rates
    {
        public MXN Mxn { get; set; }
        public ILS Ils { get; set; }
        public EUR Eur { get; set; }
        public BRL Brl { get; set; }
        public PLN Pln { get; set; }
        public MYR Myr { get; set; }
        public SEK Sek { get; set; }
        public AUD Aud { get; set; }
        public IDR Idr { get; set; }
        public TRY Try { get; set; }
        public RUB Rub { get; set; }
        public JPY Jpy { get; set; }
        public CAD Cad { get; set; }
        public USD Usd { get; set; }
        public GBP Gbp { get; set; }
        public NZD Nzd { get; set; }
        public CZK Czk { get; set; }
        public SGD Sgd { get; set; }

    public class MXN
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class ILS
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class EUR
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class BRL
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class PLN
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class MYR
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class SEK
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class AUD
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class IDR
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class TRY
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class RUB
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class JPY
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class CAD
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class USD
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class GBP
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class NZD
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class CZK
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }

        public class SGD
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I then called the API and stored the response in a string;

```
    var btcAvgClient = new RestClient();
    btcAvgClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/constants/exchangerates/local");

    IRestResponse response;
    var request = new RestRequest();

    response = btcAvgClient.Execute(request);
    string btcAvg = response.Content;
```

I believe there are 1 or 2 steps remaining but I can't quite figure it out. How do I now convert this string to something usable?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can deserialize `rates` into a `Dictionary<string, Rate>` as shown in [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) or [Parsing JSON Object with variable properties into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202496/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, modify your data model to look like the following:

```
public class Rate
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal rate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Rate> rates { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

Next, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class RateExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetConversion(this Dictionary<string, Rate> rates, string from, string to, out decimal rate)
    {
        Rate fromRate;
        Rate toRate;

        if (rates == null || !rates.TryGetValue(from, out fromRate))
        {
            rate = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if (!rates.TryGetValue(to, out toRate))
        {
            rate = 0;
            return false;
        }

        rate = toRate.rate / fromRate.rate;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, you can execute a typed request as follows.  The typed request will automatically deserialize the response into your desired data model:

```
var btcAvgClient = new RestClient("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/");
var request = new RestRequest("constants/exchangerates/local");

// Execute the request and get the typed response
var response = btcAvgClient.Execute<RootObject>(request);

// Get the root object from the response.
RootObject data = response.Data;
```

And compute the conversion from USD to CAD as follows:

```
// Compute the converson from (e.g.) USD to CAD
var fromName = "USD";
var toName = "CAD";

decimal rate;
if (data.rates.TryGetConversion(fromName, toName, out rate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Conversion from {0} to {1} = {2}", fromName, toName, rate);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot get conversion from {0} to {1}.", fromName, toName);
}
```

On my computer this outputs

> Conversion from USD to CAD = 1.36245

Which currently seems to be the correct number as confirmed by a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+1+USD+to+CAD):

> 1 United States Dollar equals 1.36 Canadian Dollar

Notes:

- Since this API might possibly return different currencies in the future, but with the same data for each, I defined `rates` to be a `Dictionary<string, Rate> rates`.  The dictionary will capture all returned currency rates.

  Your code will need to know the currency names to expect, but I believe these are standard.
- Since we are doing currency conversions here I defined `rate` to be a `decimal` rather than a `string`.  The serializer will automatically deserialize the string value for `"rate"` into a decimal.
- To ensure your request was successful see *[How to idiomatically handle HTTP error codes when using RestSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31516501/3744182)*.

  Alternatively you could check the `response.ErrorException` as shown in the [Recommended Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) documentation page.
- If you need to make `async` requests see *[How should I implement ExecuteAsync with RestSharp on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10153749/3744182)*.
- RestSharp has a [built-in JSON serializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serialization/Json/JsonSerializer.cs) but you could use Json.NET if you prefer.  Simply get the `response.Content` string and deserialize by doing:

  ```
  // Execute the request and get the untyped (string) response
  var response = btcAvgClient.Execute(request);

  // Get the root object from the response.
  RootObject data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm a beginner and am having problems understanding your code, but it's coming along nicely. I ended up solving the above, but will circle back to your code at some point to improve my own implementation. Once again I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be too root object.

```
var beers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
```